# Apt can't find package libasound2-dev 20.04 arm64

Tags: apt, 20.04, raspberrypi, arm64

I'm trying to install `libasound2-dev` on a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi 4 but `apt` reports that it can't find the package.

Running `apt search libasound2` yields:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt search libasound2
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
alsa-topology-conf/now 1.2.2-1 all [installed,local]
  ALSA topology configuration files

libasound2/now 1.2.2-2.1 arm64 [installed,local]
  shared library for ALSA applications

libasound2-data/now 1.2.2-2.1 all [installed,local]
  Configuration files and profiles for ALSA drivers

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Looking at the package repository however, it should be available for arm64: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libasound2-dev

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` is below (after removing commented lines).

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security multiverse
```

If it helps, it seems like this problem isn't specific to `libasound2-dev`. It seems that apt can't find anything in the `libdevel` section.

Comment: Strange : The arm64 download page has no links → https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libasound2-dev **arm64** → https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/arm64/libasound2-dev/download .... but can be found with Google http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that some of the files in `/var/lib/apt/lists/` were zero size, so I ran:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
sudo apt update
```

Many of the zero size files were much larger and running `apt search libasound2-dev` yielded the expected result.